# gulp-cssimport Throws Up an Error After I Make a Change

Tags: css, gruntjs, shopify, gulp

I'm trying to use the [Shopify CSS Import](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-css-import), and manage to get up to **Step 6**, where it asks me to run `grunt`. This command begins to watch my directory and once I make a change to my stylesheet it seems to work and I seem to get a success message.

```
Done, without errors.
Completed in 0.917s at Sun Jul 20 2014 16:21:17 GMT+0100 (BST) - Waiting...
```

But then straight after this line, this error is thrown up:

```
>> /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
>> : getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `request'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:93:in `perform'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty.rb:521:in `perform_request'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty.rb:483:in `put'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/shopify_theme-ca8bca3b91a2/lib/shopify_theme.rb:73:in `send_asset'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/shopify_theme-ca8bca3b91a2/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:214:in `block in send_asset'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/shopify_theme-ca8bca3b91a2/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:271:in `show_during'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/shopify_theme-ca8bca3b91a2/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:213:in `send_asset'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/shopify_theme-ca8bca3b91a2/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:135:in `block in watch'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/shopify_theme-ca8bca3b91a2/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:168:in `block in watcher'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/filewatcher-0.3.4/lib/filewatcher.rb:30:in `block in watch'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/filewatcher-0.3.4/lib/filewatcher.rb:24:in `loop'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/filewatcher-0.3.4/lib/filewatcher.rb:24:in `watch'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/shopify_theme-ca8bca3b91a2/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:167:in `watcher'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/shopify_theme-ca8bca3b91a2/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:127:in `watch'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/shopify_theme-ca8bca3b91a2/bin/theme:24:in `<top (required)>'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin/theme:23:in `load'
    >>  from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin/theme:23:in `<main>'
Watching current folder: /Users/username/Desktop/shopify-css-import-master
config.yml does not exist!
[16:21:18] Uploading: assets/theme.scss.liquid>> Exited with code: 1.
Warning: Task "exec:theme_watch" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
    Warning:  Use --force to continue.

        Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any idea what's going on here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot about the file config.yml

On the shopify-css-import page you gave they say:

> Run Shopify theme gem
>
> Make sure config.yml file is setup properly. Docs here. In a separate
>   Terminal window that is still in your theme's root, run:
>
> theme watch

Check that config.yml is there and let me know if you went further